# I need a function for C++ on a Mac like std::cin but with a timeout

Tags: c++

I have a Mac, so I don't have access to any windows.h functions, or any other windows libraries in C++. I am creating a game in C++. The controls of the game are the characters w,a,s,d. Currently I have the input method as std:cin. However, the problem is after the user types each character they must hit enter every time. Furthermore, the fact the std::cin does not timeout means that the user can essentially 'pause' the game to think about what move to make next (which ruins much of the fun of this game).

I need a function like std::cin but with a timeout of about .25 seconds. A function that will return as soon as the user types the character (without the need of the user hitting enter) would also work; but a function like std::cin with a timeout would be preferred. Please don't suggest window's library functions as I am again a Mac user using terminal.

Are there any standard c++ functions within the standard mac Libraries which will function equivalently to std::cin with a timeout of T that will run correctly in a Mac terminal?

Comment: You'll have to brew this your own. With linux/unix based systems (isn't Mac OS similarly such?) you can use a `poll()` loop listening to `fd = 1`.

Comment: [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) is for reading formatted input. You need something completely different. For example: https://www.libsdl.org/

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't use [`int istream::get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) ?

It's a blocking call though. I'm sure there is a better way to do it, but the quickest hack I can think of is to spawn a thread (just before calling `get()`) that waits for 0.25 secs and then writes some 'timeout char' say 't' to teh stream.

Comment: I cannot use cin.get() because that function as well requires the user to hit return before the program receives the character as an input.

Comment: @Zac: Not true. Apparently you have line buffering on in your terminal.

Comment: @ZacWimer `get()` and `operator >>()` work differently. That's kinda the point. `operator >>()` returns when you give it a line feed (like enter); `get()` will return on first keystroke.

Comment: I think I do, but as well in the IDE I have been using. I will try to switch it off. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ncurses` library, putting the terminal in `cbreak()` (non-blocking) mode, and disabling input delay with `nodelay()`:

```
WINDOW *window = initscr();
cbreak();
nodelay(window, TRUE);
```

Then the `getch()` function will not block, returning `ERR` if no character is ready, so you can poll it in a loop and `break` when your timeout has been reached.

However, this may also require that you use `ncurses` for screen output, which may be a dealbreaker.